# get the value from url by using php

Tags: php, url, parameters

I displayed a set of questions.

On selecting one of those questions for which I required the answers to be posted on the same page, but the problem is I am not getting id parameter from url which I am passing on selectiong the question.

Now when I am trying to answer the question which is selected, I will need the id of question to post the answer of that perticular question which I already have in url as a parameter for Example: id=1.

Here is the body section of html page:

```
     <?php
 include("menu/menu.php");
 $sqli = "SELECT * FROM forum_question where id='$id'";
 $result=mysqli_query($conn,$sqli);
    ?>

  <form action="submit_answer.php" method="post" name="answers">
     <br> <br> <br>


      <?php 
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    echo "Q".$row['detail'];
  ?>

  <br>
  answers:<br>
     <textarea class="tinymce" name="answers"></textarea>
     <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id;?>">
  <br> <br>
  <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">
```

After submit the page "submit_answer.php", Code is:

```
<?php 
include'config.php';

if($conn){
 if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

    $answers = $_REQUEST['answers'];

  $id= $_GET ['id'];
  }

   $sqli= "INSERT INTO answers (answers)
 VALUES ('$answers')";
if (mysqli_query( $conn,$sqli))
 {
     echo "New record created successfully";
   header("location:answer.php?id='$id'");

 } else {
  echo "Error: " . $sqli . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }
}else{              

}

 mysqli_close($conn);


?>
```

Basically I am very much fresher in Php I just want to know how should I get the id of question and submit it to the "submit_answer.php" with the answer content.

Comment: provide your html and js code to

Comment: Your SQL queries are unfortunately wide open to injection attacks. Please switch to PDO, which provides prepared statements and bound parameters, which help mitigate the security flaws. As you are new to php, I really recommend reading through http://www.phptherightway.com/ which goes over common pitfalls that you can find in older tutorials.

Comment: @jedifans — mysqli (which the OP is already using) also supports prepared statements and bound parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change it (add hidden input for id in markup html)

```
<?php 
include'config.php';
//session_start();
$id= $_GET ['id'];

?>

<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="tinymce/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="tinymce/plugin/tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="tinymce/plugin/tinymce/init-tinymce.js"></script>
</head>
  <body>
    <div id="container">
      <div id="main">


      <?php
      include("menu/menu.php");
      $sqli = "SELECT * FROM forum_question where id='$id'";
      $result=mysqli_query($conn,$sqli);
      ?>

    <form action="submit_answer.php" method="post" name="answers">
      <br> <br> <br>
      <?php 
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
         echo "Q".$row['detail'];
      ?>

      <br>answers:<br>
      <textarea class="tinymce" name="answers"></textarea>
      <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id;?>">
      <br> <br>
      <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

submit_answer.php

```
<?php 
include'config.php';

if($conn){
  if (isset($_POST['answers']) && isset($_POST['id'])) {
    $answers = $_POST['answers'];
    $id= $_POST['id'];

    $sqli= "INSERT INTO answers (answers) VALUES ('$answers')";
    if (mysqli_query( $conn,$sqli))
    {
      echo "New record created successfully";
      header("location:answer.php?id='$id'");

    } else {
      echo "Error: " . $sqli . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }
  }
  mysqli_close($conn);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

just take a hidden field below the answer field and get the url parameter to that hidden field on page load, as said by user buivankim2020 and submit submit_answer.php,

after submit get the value of that field in variable like what you do for getting the answer..